# Should I start writing new apps in MVC 6 + EF7, or should I do them in MVC 5 + EF6 and later on upgrade?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have some personal projects going on. I know that both MVC 6 and EF7 aren't finished yet, and they are more prone to bugs. I did watch some videos from msdn telling that ASP.NET 5 will allow running legacy ASP.NET MVC 5 projects out of the box. The only problem is that I wouldn't be able to only use the ASP.NET Core (which only weighs 11 MB) vs the complete one (220+ MB)

I don't want to spend hours and hours figuring out how to do x or y on the new platform. I have a new project that I started, and I've only developed the visual part. I'd like to know if I should start writing the app on MVC 6 and EF7.

I'm planning on launching it in the following weeks to the web.

### Edit

It's better for me to explain what's the project about. I'm building a "gaming - tournament" platform. On the server side won't by anything complicated. Much of the effects and data display will be JavaScript driven.

The web app will do the following:

- Serve as a news site.
- Allow people to register for a tournament and keep their own ranking in there
- Use the website to organize tournaments in real time, and communicate through devices (Tablets, and Mobile Phones) on a leaderboard.

There's nothing that the site will not be able to accomplish without current technology. Is that just I don't want to start something anew knowing there's something more future proof around the corner.

Comment: really it's based on your situation...

Comment: @teo van kot: Is it ok then for me to start using MVC 6? I"ll be the one who'll be personally managing it. How painful is it to upgrade to RC and RTW releases?

Comment: i suppose it's really better to update that to find all early release errrors.

Comment: I don't think EF7 even has feature parity with EF6 yet, so unless your needs happen to be very limited (and unlilkely to grow rapidly) you should probably stick with EF6. Reportedly they're going to expend some effort on the EF6 -> EF7 migration story, so it shouldn't be too bad. Can't comment on MVC.

Comment: I believe that the major "drawback" from EF6 to EF7 is that the latter one will impose Code First (please correct me if I'm wrong). Fortunately, that's my preferred way on coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's more important/essential in your project requirements, maintenance/expandability or reliability? If it's the first one then go with the beta new version (MVC 6 with the new .NET Framework and EF7). Otherwise go with the latest stable release version (MVC 5 with .NET 4.5 and EF6).

Having said that, I personally think that ASP.NET MVC 5 is more suitable for your particular case since your project is not quite large (knowing that you'll be able to finish it within weeks). Such a decision would've been debatable if the project/investment you're about to make is a long term one (5+ months).

Comment: I'm going to finish it in a couple of weeks (the first stage). Later on I'll be planning on expanding it with a couple of features. Nothing as of yet, that MVC 5, Web API 2.2 and SignalR can't handle.